# Add 'has_children' class to parent li when modifying Walker_Nav_Menu

Tags: menus

I'm writing a customised walker class for wp_nav_menu and want to be able to specify if an li contains a submenu. So I want my markup to be:

```
<li class="has_children [other-wordpress-classes]">
    <a class="parent-link">Some item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
```

I know how to add and remove the classes fine, I just cant find anything to tell me if the current item has children items.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`start_el()` should get this information in its `$args` parameter, but it appears [WordPress only fills this in if `$args` is an array](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L126), while for the custom navigation menus it is an object. This is reported in [a Trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15214). But no problem, you can fill this in yourself, if you also override the `display_element()` method in your custom walker (because this is the easiest place to access the child element array):

```
class WPSE16818_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output )
    {
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
        if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
            $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
        }
        return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        if ( $args->has_children ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Jan, Can you help me with [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41116/wordpress-nav-menu-using-twitter-bootstrap)? I tried your code but i couldn't make it work. Can you give me some more sample code?

Comment: Refer to the [complete implementation example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89696/8495) further down on this page.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jan fabry.. I was held up with my custom walker.. Atlast your snippet helped me.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** As of [WordPress 3.7](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/25602) (October 2013), CSS classes have been added to indicate child menu items and pages in theme menus — no need to use a custom walker as it's taken care of in WordPress core.

The CSS classes are named `menu-item-has-children` and `page_item_has_children`.

---

For a complete solution for anybody in a hurry (credit to Jan Fabry's previous answer), see the full implementation below.

Output the navigation in your theme's template:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'navigation-primary',
    'container' => false,
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id' => '',
    'menu_class' => '',
    'menu_id' => '',
    'walker' => new Selective_Walker(),
    'depth' => 2
    )
);
```

Then, include the following in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
class Selective_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

        if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
            $args[0]->has_children = !empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
        }

        return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        if ( $args->has_children ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'has_children';
        }

        parent::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }
}
```

The resulting HTML output will resemble the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="has_children"><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="has_children"><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

For more information on using WordPress' walker class, see [Understanding the Walker Class](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/).

Enjoy!

Comment: Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in D:\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\wpt_theme\functions.php on line 44

Comment: Line#44 is parent::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args);

Answer (score 2):

This function is exactly what you want to have. It also shows you a pretty effective way to modify nav menu items. Furthermore you can open it for more advanced (eg. child theme) functions via the item-filter:

```
/**
 * Classes for a navigation named "Topnav" in the nav location "top".
 * Shows examples on how to modify the current nav menu item
 * 
 * @param (object) $items
 * @param (object) $menu
 * @param (object) $args
 */
function wpse16818_nav_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args )
{
    # >>>> start editing

    // examples for possible targets
    $target['name'] = 'Topnav';
    // The targeted menu item/s
    $target['items'] = array( (int) 6 );

    # <<<< stop editing

    // filter for child themes: "config_nav_menu_topnav"
    $target = apply_filters( 'config_nav_menu_'.strtolower( $target['name'] ), $target );

    // Abort if we're not with the named menu
    if ( $menu->name !== $target['name'] ) 
        return;

    foreach ( $items as $item )
    {
        // Check what $item contains
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($item); echo '</pre>';

        // First real world example:
        $item->classes = 'span-4';

        // Second real world example:
        // Append this class if we are in one of the targeted items
        if ( in_array( (int) $item->menu_order, $target['items'] ) )
            $item->classes .= ' last';
    }

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpse16818_nav_menu_items', 10, 3 );
```

*And yes, there's - in nearly every case - no need for a custom walker.*

Comment: Thanks, I need the walker for now but will have a look at this for next time round!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make drop down, you can do it with css only.
make custom nav in WP with children, WordPress automatically assigns class .sub-menu to child ul. Try this CSS

```
    nav li {position:relative;}
   .sub-menu {display:none; position:absolute; width:300px;}
    nav ul li:hover ul {display:block;}
```

You may want to add some jQuery to spice it up a little, but this should give you a working drop down menu.

Comment: Thanks, its for a multilevel collapsible tree menu that I'm inserting control elements into as well, but definitely good to do as much with css as possible!

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( $this->has_children ) {
    $item_output .= 'has_children';
}
```

Comment: Please, explain what this code does and how it is answer the question.

Comment: And please post the code in more context. As is, most people who visit will have no idea where to try to paste that and will get it wrong.