# I am extending Walker_Nav_Menu: How can I get the number of children elements of the current item?

Tags: php, menus, walker

I am trying to extend the Walker_Nav_Menu walker to make some changes to the way WP outputs menus. The method I have to override is start_el, so I created my Walker and copied the base method:

```
<?php
class myCustom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}  
?>
```

My problem is that I dont seem able to get the children for the current item ($item). Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in a very similar question. The accepted solution worked perfectly for me, although it involves fixing a wordpress bug...

[Add 'has_children' class to parent li when modifying Walker_Nav_Menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16818/add-has-children-class-to-parent-li-when-modifying-walker-nav-menu)

Answer (score 0):

count (get_children($item));

Does that help?

Comment: It doesnt work... For some reason it returns 11 for all menu items, even though mymenu has only 5 items in total. Weird

Comment: What does the print_r look like?

Comment: I would also try get_pages with arguments of child_of($item). If you also add the parent=$item, it will only go one layer deep.