# wp_nav_menu: check if the list item has children and add a class to anchor link

Tags: navigation

I'm trying to add a class to anchor links of children element in wp_nav_menu both for pages and posts. 
Is there a way to modify the Nav Menu Walker and do so?

Basically my custom walker looks like this:

```
class Main_Nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
        function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
        }
        function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {

            if( $depth == 0) {
                    $output .= "<li class='menu'>";
            }               
            if( $depth == 1) {
                    $output .= "<li>";
            }
            $attributes  = '';
            ! empty( $item->attr_title ) and $attributes .= ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
            ! empty( $item->target )and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"';
            ! empty( $item->xfn )and $attributes .= ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"';
            ! empty( $item->url )and $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"';

            $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

            if (/* THE MENU ELEMENT HAS CHILDREN */) {
                    $item_output = 
                    "<a $attributes class='menu'>"
                    . $title
                    . '</a> ';
            }

            else {
                    $item_output = 
                    "<a $attributes>"
                    . $title
                    . '</a> ';
            }

            $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth);

    }

}
```

As you see I don't know what the proper condition instead of `/* THE ELEMENT HAS CHILDREN */`.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Tamil I updated the code as follows:

```
class Main_Nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
        function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
        }
        function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {

            if( $depth == 0) {
                    $output .= "<li class='menu'>";
            }               
            if( $depth == 1) {
                    $output .= "<li>";
            }
            $attributes  = '';
            ! empty( $item->attr_title ) and $attributes .= ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
            ! empty( $item->target )and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"';
            ! empty( $item->xfn )and $attributes .= ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"';
            ! empty( $item->url )and $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"';

            $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

            global $wpdb;
            $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status ='publish' AND post_type='nav_menu_item' AND post_parent=%d", $item->ID);
            $child_count = $wpdb->get_var($query);

            if($child_count > 0) { /* THE MENU ELEMENT HAS CHILDREN */
                 $item_output = 
                    "<a $attributes class='menu'>"
                    . $title
                    . '</a> ';
            } else {
                    $item_output = 
                    "<a $attributes>"
                    . $title
                    . '</a> ';
            }

            $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth);

    }

}
```

No luck though :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to add a "parent" CSS class to the anchor tag of menu items who have children by following this answer: [Add 'has_children' class to parent li when modifying Walker_Nav_Menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16818/add-has-children-class-to-parent-li-when-modifying-walker-nav-menu)

Here's an example:

```
class Main_Nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  /**
   * @see Walker::start_el()
   * @since 3.0.0
   *
   * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
   * @param object $item Menu item data object.
   * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
   * @param int $current_page Menu item ID.
   * @param object $args
   */
  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    // Check our custom has_children property.
    if ( $args->has_children ) {
      $attributes .= ' class="menu parent"';
    }

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }

  function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
    if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
      $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
    }
    return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
  }

}
```

Comment: in my case `$args->walker->has_children` is correct (maybe something have been changed in `Walker_Nav_Menu` base class two years later

Answer (score 4):

The other way is very simple and may be useful for some people

```
/**
* Custom Nav Classes
* https://v123.tw
*/
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'v123_nav_class' , 10 , 2 );
function v123_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'other-wordpress-classes';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the items used are from the table `{$wpdb->prefix}posts`, then you can query for posts with

> post_parent = $item->ID and post_status = 'publish'

If the query returns any post then it has children and you can add the required class.

If its for pages the code in following page can be used.

http://www.jeangalea.com/wordpress/check-wordpress-page-childrensubpages/

However there doesn't seems to be a direct way to find if child exists.

UPDATE:
Added code as per your request.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status ='publish' AND post_type='nav_menu_item' AND post_parent=%d", $item->ID);
$child_count = $wpdb->get_var($query);
if($child_count > 0) { /* THE MENU ELEMENT HAS CHILDREN */
   .....
} else {
   .....
}
```

Comment: I believe the question is if the Menu Item has children not the post or page.

Comment: @tamil, how would the code look like with your suggestions?

Comment: @Sergey Added code as per your request.

Comment: I tried yr code, but it didnt work. Please note, I'm using pages not posts. Is there any difference?

Comment: @KevinLangleyJr. Thanks for pointing out. I overlooked the question.

Comment: @Sergey it wont make difference. You can use it for any nav menu item. Can you give link to your page where you test it?

Comment: @tamilsweet, I updated my question. I can't give you the link - no use in ready html :)

Comment: @Sergey I doubt if you are using WordPress nav menu. Try removing `AND post_type='nav_menu_item' ` from the query.

Comment: I removed it and still useless.

Comment: It should work, manually run the query in your db and check if you are getting result for the query. Use debug echo statement to print out query string and the count you get. This is the only way you can get it work.